# Upload files by JSP Servlet in secure

Tags: security, jsp, servlets, web

This question may be wider. But please consider a file uploading point of a jsp servlet application. When a jsp site has allowed to users to upload files ( images, text files,media files..etc),some one can upload some vulnerable files which can be a threaten to the application or container/server. If an antivirus application has been installed,it may rise against it(I think so).
Is there any action that we can get to check the files whether they are acceptable or not?. (For example, check the file and their file extension and whether they are in real file extensions.or Is there any executable hidden files..) . Any link with code samples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you worried about attacks against your application / server, or are about your site being used to distribute malicious content to its users?

Comment: @Kasperle Thanks. Tt is against the attacks against the application and its container/server. I think that if we can protect against such threatens, the application can be avoided from being used to distribute malicious content to its users. If you have a better solution, let me know please.